# Retrieving data from Sqlite database and plot it in graph for android application

Tags: android, sqlite, graph

Is there any existing example that requires data to be retrieved from Sqlite database and plot it in XY graphs??

Answer (score 2):

You might find the following two links of help, the first one will show you how to use the SQLlite database using examples and the second one will has examples of how to plot a graph in android

[Using SQLlite database](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

[How to plot a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/7362757#7362757)

Comment: I am able to retrieve text data frm sqlite.. I am aso able to create a graph but the coordinates are manually added in the class file. But i am unable to find the codes required to retrieve data frm database and plot it in graph..